# How to find page views by URL in Google Analytics

Tags: report, google-analytics-4, pageviews

In GA4, how do I find page views by URL?

The Landing page Engagement report shows 0 which I know is inaccurate. I know this because we already have so many people signing up using that link.  I plugged in the URl above the report.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Landing page would be the first url of a user's session.  To view all urls, maybe try the "pages and screens" report under "Engagement".  Alternatively, you could create a custom report under Explore -> New Freefrom report & then select "Page path and screen class" or "Page path + query string" as your row and "Views" as your metric.